# Hibernate Select query returns null foreign object

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa-2.1

I have the following entities defined:
Restaurante:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurantes")
public class Restaurante implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private Set<Menu> menus = new HashSet<>(0);

    public Restaurante() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "restaurante_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurante")
    public Set<Menu> getMenus() {
        return menus;
    }

    public void setMenus(Set<Menu> menus) {
        this.menus = menus;
    }
}
```

And menu:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "menus")
public class Menu implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private Restaurante restaurante;

    public Menu() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "menu_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurante_id", nullable = false)
    public Restaurante getRestaurante() {
        return restaurante;
    }

    public void setRestaurante(Restaurante Restaurante) {
        this.restaurante = restaurante;
    }
}
```

And when I perform the following query:

```
public Menu getMenuById(Integer id) throws HibernateException, IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    session = HibernateSessionService.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    criteria = session.createCriteria(Menu.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
    return (Menu) criteria.list().get(0);
}
```

The property restaurante is null.
There is a restaurante loaded in the database with the Id I'm using, and there are several menus loaded with that foreign key as well.

Can someone give me advice or help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ORM model and criteria query looks fine. What version of Hibernate are you using? Could you please paste your Hibernate configuration?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I actually got the answer but forgt to update here. I was missing logic in the setter and constructor that made sure the if menu didnt have a restaurante, it would then add it to the object and vice versa.